# Weka CSVSaver indexing issue

Tags: java, weka, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using Weka to implement a bunch of NLP algorithms. For this, I want to write the datasets I create (from plain texts) to csv files. The instances are created properly. I have tested the instance creation process by manually checking very small parts of the dataset (e.g. just two texts with 10 words each). I have also used Weka's k-means clusterer directly on the instances I create, and it runs flawlessly.

But, when I try to use `CSVSaver` to save the instances to a file, I get an indexOutOfBoundsException. As far as I can see, both the methods `Saver#writeBatch()` and `Saver#writeIncremental()` are looping all the way up to and including the length of the instance. That baffles me! Java is 0-indexed, and an `instance` object is also 0-indexed. So why is Weka looping until `size()` and not `size() - 1`? Am I missing something extremely obvious here?

The relevant portion of the code is as follows:

```
CSVSaver csvSaver = new CSVSaver();
csvSaver.setFieldSeparator("\t");
csvSaver.setFile(new File(optionSet.valueOf("doc-output").toString()));
csvSaver.setMaxDecimalPlaces(3);
csvSaver.setNoHeaderRow(false);
csvSaver.setInstances(documentInstances);
csvSaver.setRetrieval(AbstractSaver.INCREMENTAL);
for (Instance instance : csvSaver.getInstances())
    csvSaver.writeIncremental(instance);
```

The very first iteration of the `for` loop writes the header row, which contains 346 elements (indexed from 0 to 345). Weka writes all of them, and then throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 346, Size: 346
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at weka.core.Instances.attribute(Instances.java:341)
    at weka.core.AbstractInstance.toString(AbstractInstance.java:744)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVSaver.instanceToString(CSVSaver.java:578)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVSaver.writeIncremental(CSVSaver.java:472)
```

Why is Weka going all the way to index 346, when even a Java beginner knows to stop at 345?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way around this by forcing each instance to be a `DenseInstance` as follows:

```
for (Instance instance : csvSaver.getInstances()) {
    csvSaver.writeIncremental(new DenseInstance(instance));
}
```

This works perfectly, and of course, the csv output is correct.

This solution is only a work-around, though, and I would prefer it if someone finds the real reason behind this error.

Comment: I stalked the Weka mailing lists for a while and there seems to be a bug pertaining to `SparseInstance` objects. I didn't understand the nature of that bug, to be perfectly honest. So, if someone knows about this bug, please share the knowledge.